# It is possible to implement multitouch zoom with Api Level 3 (1.5) app?

Tags: android, multi-touch

I need to implement multitouch zoom (like iphone) on my app. I need to do zoom on a GLSurfaceView class that shows a polygon.

This app must be for 1.5 android phones.

It is possible to do it? Can someone explain me how and give me some examples?

Thanks

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668828/android-1-5-multitouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitively after days of search i think it is not possible to make apps that works with 1.5 Android and multitouch

Comment: have you looked in the compatibility package? I'm not quite sure but this would be the first place to look for a feature that was introduced in a later version